# opencv starts capture with a big zoom

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video-capture

I am building a stereo vision system, but when I start my videoCapture with opencv, the frame is zoomed. Instead of showing the whole face with background for example, it only shows a big zoom to the chin.

It is USB camera bought on Amazon, just a PCB with lens and USB cable. I can only set the focus with a screw on the lens.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Yes, it is happening in some machines, then you can manually set the width and the height with `cap.set(prop, value);` on the start while capture has been successfully opened.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil  yes i have try that after the cv2.VideoCapture(0) but basically, it only changed the resolution but still with the zoom in it.
i even tried to resize the frame with the interpolation as INTER_AREA and INTER_CUBIC

Comment: I have bought this camera for your information :
[camera](http://www.elpcctv.com/industrial-usb-720p-camera-module-for-monochrome-stereo-p-79.html)

Comment: You should check if you can do it with the camera's settings, I think the camera may have the corresponding settings. I was the camera properties as you sent the link above, it supports any kind of resolutions you need, so you can try to select 640x480.

Comment: dear @BahramdunAdil Yes i have tried to do this with cap.set(3, 640) and cap.set(4, 480)
It indeed changes the resolution but the zoom was still here.

Comment: No, I mean, you can change settings to the camera itself not the capture within OpenCV. The camera you bought must have the setting to change its resolution, you should check the manual of the camera, or contact the camera technical support to show you.

Comment: I have tried to modified the setting using 'v4l2-ctl -d dev/video0 --set-fmt-video' before running the opencv script but without success. The video still has the same resolution with the zoom in it.
i also sent an email to the maker.